# Setting up a WYSIWYG editor for Drupal site users

Tags: drupal

Looking through the [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) contrib modules, and after a few Google searches, it becomes evident that there are any number of choices and combos available to set up a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor in Drupal.  I'm hoping that I can do this as simply and quickly and painlessly as possible, and not have to keep trying out different combos till one actually works right.

Here's what I need:

1. A basic WYSIWYG editor for the "filtered" input type only.
2. It doesn't need to have image-insert necessarily, though that might be nice later on...
3. Simple to set up and maintain.
4. Needs to work for Content-Profiles, Blog, Forum-post, and a few custom content types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the wysiwyg (http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module.. it lets you install and try out a range of different editors, and you can associate different editors to different input types.

Personally, I've found fckeditor a good choice for allowing editors to author content - but I think the final choice is down to personal preference.  By using the wysiwyg module you can demo a range.

Comment: +1: WYSIWYG is the best choice, since it lets you use any number of different editors, and switch them out as needed. Choosing an editor will be your bigger problem. If you're willing to commit to just one editor, I would recommend YUI (and the accompanying drupal module) based on your specs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the YUI editor first.  I'm sure it's a good thing to have all these different editor choices, but I hate to have to spend all the time finding the best one...

Comment: I'm personally a huge fan of FCK - really nice module, good profiles for setting what users can do - easy to set up and customize!

Comment: I like fckeditor a lot too .. it's pretty easy to skin too .. so it doesn't need to look ugly.

Comment: i recommend the fckeditor evolution which is called CKeditor (http://ckeditor.com/) and is far better than its predecessor

Comment: @gpilotino, I've heard it's good - but AFAIK, it hasn't been integrated to function via the wysiwyg module yet..? as soon as it's available I'll definitely try it out.

Comment: there's a patch: http://drupal.org/node/462146 (working for me)

Comment: btw, better formats (http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) can help you configure per-node-type input formats.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> Allows the use of client-side editors to edit content. It simplifies the installation and integration of the editor of your choice. This module replaces all other editor integration modules. No other Drupal module is required.
>
> The Wysiwyg module supports any kind of client-side editor including HTML editors (a.k.a. WYSIWYG), "pseudo-editors" (buttons to insert markup into a textarea), or even Flash-based applications. The editor library must be downloaded separately. Various editors are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg recommendation. But this thing is just about what I expected.  A million configuration choices, and not one of them working right yet.  I've already spent 2 hours on it, and have tried:
FCKeditor
YUI
markItUp 
NicEdit

Setting up YUI from the wysiwyg config page didn't work.  When I downloaded the 2 YUI modules and installed, they work, but not with wysiwyg module, and they broke my content profiles when I uninstalled them.  So far the only one that actually seems to work is the ugly FCKeditor.

So yes, it's just the time-eater I was expecting and hoping against.

EDIT:  Looks like wysiwyg/tinyMCE combo is the ticket.  Works and looks okay.  Thanks for all the info!

Comment: You can skin FCKeditor to look nice.. you need to edit fckconfig.js to do so though.

Comment: There is a great presentation here about how to set up http://www.archive.org/details/HowtoeasilysetupanintiutiveWYSIWYGeditorthatsupportsinlineimageplacementusingCCKimagefields

Answer (score 1):

I use the [Wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module - be sure to follow the directions closely. FCKEditor and TinyMCE work with it nicely, some of the others one are not working well.

UPDATE - April, 2010 -

Use the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, very easy - still alot of choices though. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... will allow Drupal to replace textarea fields with the CKEditor - a visual HTML editor, usually called a WYSIWYG editor. This HTML text editor brings many of the powerful WYSIWYG editing functions of known desktop editors like Word to the web. It's very fast and doesn't require any kind of installation on the client computer.

Answer (score 1):

To sit along side the wysiwyg module, I also make use of a module called [better formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats)

This modules allows you to further refine which input filter to use by default for each node type. I thought that alone was spot on but, you can also set up per node, which users roles  get allocated which filter type.

This means on your blog pages, trusted users can have full html access (which will bring up the wysisywg - on my config) whilst other users just get a bog standard text box.

Once installed, all the options for it can be found in each node type's edit screen.

*I make great use of it on my mini community portal for a little town in the UK, [Tunstall](http://www.bankeyfields.co.uk)*

Answer (score 1):

I had tested several Editors WYSIWIG before and now I can recommend you the [FCKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with no problem.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1suHskbL1pE) a how to install video

[Here](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Users_Guide) a good user guide